# What is wrong with this SQL statement in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am using Python and a MySQL database and am attempting to itterate through rows in a CSV file and insert them in my database. I have the following:

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="root",
    database="mydb")

cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0")
csv_data = pd.read_csv("file path")
sql = "INSERT INTO table (ID, SecondID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
for index, row in csv_data.iterrows():
    cursor.execute(sql, row)
cursor.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1")
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
mydb.close()
```

I can't see what's wrong with the SQL.
**Getting the following error:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '%s, %s, %s, %s)'

**NOTE** - The rest of the code seems to work okay and the SQL works fine if I insert specific values but when I try to use the %s construct it fails yet other responses I have seen appear to recommend this as the correct syntax.

**Please help-  what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: It's worth checking what [parameter style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) you're using.

Comment: Is your table really called "table"? Is that allowed?

Comment: anyway, why there are %s without any variables ? eg "%s"%(string)

Comment: @sygneto That is how statement parameters work.

Comment: If your table really named table, the table name must be quoted by backtics

Comment: @khelwood as far as it's in `` (all the calls to it), it is allowed, but not recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you better use pandas to_sql function.
I'm not sure whether `mysql.connector` works so i'll use `sqlalchemy`.
It looks like that:

```
ENGINE = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3306/mydb')
with ENGINE.connect() as connection:
    ENGINE.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0")
    csv_data.to_sql('table_name', connection, if_exists='append', index=False)
    ENGINE.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like that the problem is that you are invoking the query without scape the value.

The `execute` function its getting a class and not an array

```
for index, row in csv_data.iterrows():
    cursor.execute(sql, row)
```

You should generate an array with all the values and then invoke the query.

Something like:

```
for index, row in csv_data.iterrows():
    params = map(lambda x : x.value, row)
    cursor.execute(sql,params)
```

Be carefull, the size of the array has to be the same size as the values params.
In this case 4

Answer (score 0):

Thank you that was very helpful, I made one minor change and it works perfectly now. Here is the final solution I used:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3306/mydb')

csv_data = pd.read_csv("file path")
engine.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0")

with engine.connect() as connection:
    csv_data.to_sql('table', connection, if_exists='append', index=False)

engine.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1")
```